# VBA code to add days from one column to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having the following columns in Excel: **Document Date** (all cells have values) & **Initial Disposition Date** (there're blanks within the column).

Each *Document Date* cell corresponds to an *Initial Disposition Date* cell.

For any **blank** Initial Disposition Date cells, I'd like to set them to be 7 days from the corresponding *Document Date*. (Strictly blank cells)

Ex: Document Date = 10/01/2018. Desired Initial Disposition Date = 10/08/2018.

Is there a code to execute such action? (I have approximately 55,000 rows and 51 columns by the way).

Thank you very much! Any suggestions or ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please have a read here to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people answer your question, and review the following [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.

Comment: @garfbradaz, if you type the shorthand `[mcve]` into a comment you will get [mcve]. Same for `[ask]`, `[help]` and a few others. e.g. [ask] and [help].

Comment: @Jeeped :Wow I did not know that - thanks!

Comment: In your `Initial Disposition Date` column put `=[Document Date] + 7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through a range is a little quicker in this case. I am assuming your **data** is on `Sheet1`, your **Document Date** is on `Column A` and your **Initial Deposition** is on `Column B`.

Last, you need to determine if you want that 7 days to be inclusive of weekends or not. I left you a solution for both. You will need to remove one of the action statements (in middle of loop)

```
Option Explicit

Sub BetterCallSaul()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LRow As Long, iRange As Range, iCell As Range

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set iRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & LRow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each iCell In iRange
        If iCell = "" Then
            iCell = iCell.Offset(, -1) + 7 'Includes Weekends
            iCell = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(iCell.Offset(, -1), 7) 'Excludes Weekends
        End If
    Next iCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I also recommend changing the sub name ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your Document Date is on Column A and you Initial Disposition Date in Column B, then the following would achieve your desired results:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 2 To Lastrow
'loop from row 2 to the last row with data
    If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then
    'if there is no value in Column B then
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value + 7
        'add seven days to the date from Column A
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A formula on all blanks would avoid the delays looping through the worksheet column(s).

```
Sub ddPlus7()

    Dim dd As Long, didd As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        'no error control on the next two lines so those header labels better be there
        dd = Application.Match("Document Date", .Rows(1), 0)
        didd = Application.Match("Desired Initial Disposition Date", .Rows(1), 0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With Intersect(.Columns(dd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow, _
                       .Columns(didd).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow, _
                       .Columns(didd))
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[" & dd - didd & "]+7"
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

End Sub
```